# Copy an encrypted message in outlook redemption without decrypting it

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption

I want to do the following (pseudo-code) with outlook API or outlook redemption

```
var sourceMessage = Folder.Item[count];
//Check if source is encryted
if(sourceMessage is EncryptedMessageType)
{
  //Created a new message on target destination, and copy encrypted bytes
  var targetItem = TargetFolder.Items.Add(EncrytedMessageType)
  targetItem.Body = sourceMessage.Body;
  targetItem.EncryptionType = sourceMessage.EncryptionType;
  targetItem.Save();
}
```

Is this possible?

I looked up the RDOEncryptedMessage object but all the proprieties looks read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not copy the source message (sourceMessage)?

sourceMessage .CopyTo(TargetFolder) should do the job.

Comment: If I do that with outlook, the encrypting tool pop-up for credentials on each message and it is copied unencrypted. Are you saying that it wont be the case with redemption?

Comment: No, Redemption will not pop up anything like that.